# Calculating average of pair numbers

Tags: c

Hello I have been working on a program in C that calculates numbers and it gives me back an average. Now I'm having issues implementing code that will ask a user to enter any number of pairs and calculate the average. Below is the code that I been working on. I'm able to change the while (count < 5)to 10 to get more pairs, but my goal is to ask a user to input any PAIR and THEN calculate the average (re iterating).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

int count;
double avg, value, weight, sum, sumw;

count = 0;
sum = 0;
sumw = 0;
avg = 0.0;

while (count < 5) {
printf("Enter value and it's weight:");

scanf("%lf %lf", &value, &weight);
if (weight >= 0) {
    sumw = sumw + weight;
    sum = sum + value * weight;
    count = count + 1;
 } 
 else { printf("weight must be positive\n");
 }
 }
 avg = sum / sumw;
 printf("average is %lf\n " , avg );
 return 0;
  }
```

**Second part ** On this on I'm not too sure how to make it to PAIRS plus calculate avg. ej: 2 1 , 2 4 , 4 4 etc.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int i,n,Sum=0,numbers;
float Average;

printf("\nPlease Enter How many pairs do you want?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\nPlease Enter the elements one by one\n");
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
scanf("%d",&numbers);
Sum = Sum +numbers;
 }

Average = Sum/n;
printf("\nAverage of the %d Numbers = %.2f",n, Average);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and how the output should be.

Comment: weight must be positive, but value not?

Comment: Stop using `void main()`; prefer `int main(void)` or, when you need to access command-line arguments, `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Answer (score 2):

> but my goal is to ask a user to input any PAIR and THEN calculate the

Well, then you need to store the values somewhere. Recommendation: Have a struct for:

```
typedef struct
{
    double value;
    double weight; 
} Pair;
```

Then as soon as you have got number of pairs to read from user, create an array of pairs:

```
Pair* pairs = malloc(number * sizeof(*pairs));
```

Very important: Every `malloc` should go with a `free` to avoid memory leaks. General recommendation: plan the `free` immediately when or even before `malloc`ing.

Now inside your loop, you can fill the pairs:

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &pairs[i].value, &pairs[weight].weight);
```

Analogously, you can then use the pairs in the array in next loop or for whatever other purpose.

Side note:

```
if (weight >= 0)
{
    // ...
} 
else
{
    // printf("weight must be positive\n");
}
```

If user gave negative input, you'll be just skipping some values (or or as in loop proposed, still retain the negative values!).

You might instead read inside a nested loop *until* value is valid. Additionally consider user providing non-numeric input, too! In that case, you couldn't read a double at all. So general rule is: **Always** check the result of `scanf`:

```
if(scanf("%lf %lf", &value, &weight) != 2 || value < 0 || weight < 0)
//                                             ^
// assuming negative value not desired either
{
    // user input was invalid!!!
}
```